# Python pygame refactoring... wrapping code into a method

Tags: python, duplicates, pygame, refactoring

I have the following duplicate code in a mainloop for directional keys, `WASD` in a pygame app that I am trying to re-factor.  I'm having a difficult time trying to find the best way.  I have instances created of a PLAYER class `p` a GAME class `g` and a WORLD class `w`.

Ideally I want to make a method in the `GAME` class called, `updatePositions`. The main problem I am up against is because I have to -= or += and I am finding it hard to do without writing a whole if statement for a separate WASD key.  There has to be a better way.

```
       if event.key == pygame.K_w:
          p.fov.y -= g.pixelUpdate
          for ent in w.entityList:
            ent.rect.y += g.pixelUpdate
            ent.collisionRect.y += g.pixelUpdate
          for ent in w.ents_in_fov:
            if p.collision(ent):
              p.collided = True
              for ent in w.entityList:
                ent.rect.y -= g.pixelUpdate
                ent.collisionRect.y -= g.pixelUpdate
              p.fov.y += g.pixelUpdate

        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
          p.fov.x += g.pixelUpdate
          for ent in w.entityList:
            ent.rect.x -= g.pixelUpdate
            ent.collisionRect.x -= g.pixelUpdate
          for ent in w.ents_in_fov:
            if p.collision(ent):
              p.collided = True
              for ent in w.entityList:
                ent.rect.x += g.pixelUpdate
                ent.collisionRect.x += g.pixelUpdate
              p.fov.x -= g.pixelUpdate

        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
          p.fov.y += g.pixelUpdate
          for ent in w.entityList:
            ent.rect.y -= g.pixelUpdate
            ent.collisionRect.y -= g.pixelUpdate
          for ent in w.ents_in_fov:
            if p.collision(ent):
              p.collided = True
              for ent in w.entityList: 
                ent.rect.y += g.pixelUpdate
                ent.collisionRect.y += g.pixelUpdate
              p.fov.y -= g.pixelUpdate

        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
          p.fov.x -= g.pixelUpdate
          for ent in w.entityList:
            ent.rect.x += g.pixelUpdate
            ent.collisionRect.x += g.pixelUpdate
          for ent in w.ents_in_fov:
            if p.collision(ent):
              p.collided = True
              for ent in w.entityList:
                ent.rect.x -= g.pixelUpdate
                ent.collisionRect.x -= g.pixelUpdate
              p.fov.x += g.pixelUpdate
```

Comment: C'mon help a noob out, look at all that horrible repeated code

Comment: hint: instead of `a -= b` you can use `a += -b` so you can create one function with `a += x` and execute it with `x = b` or with `x = -b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint 1:** instead of `a -= b` you can use `a += -b`

**hint 2:** you can use value `0`

```
p.fov.x += 0
p.fov.y += g.pixelUpdate

p.fov.x += g.pixelUpdate
p.fov.y += 0
```

So you can create `updatePositions(x, y)` and execute as

```
if event.key == pygame.K_w:
    updatePositions(0, -g.pixelUpdate)

elif event.key == pygame.K_s
    updatePositions(0, g.pixelUpdate)

elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
    updatePositions(g.pixelUpdate, 0)

elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
    updatePositions(-g.pixelUpdate, 0)
```

---

**EDIT:** something like this:

```
def updatePositions(x, y):    
      p.fov.x += x
      p.fov.y += y

      for ent in w.entityList:
        ent.rect.x -= x
        ent.rect.y -= y
        ent.collisionRect.x -= x
        ent.collisionRect.x -= y

      for ent in w.ents_in_fov:
        if p.collision(ent):
          p.collided = True
          for ent in w.entityList:
            ent.rect.x += x
            ent.rect.y += y
            ent.collisionRect.x += x
            ent.collisionRect.y += y
          p.fov.x -= x
          p.fov.y -= y
```

**BTW:** it may need `updatePositions(x, y, p, w)` to get access to `p` and `w`

Comment: This is perfect, this is exactly what I needed.  I didn't know I could do `x += -1` to be the same as `x -= 1` -- It's beautiful. And it's turned a massive light on in my head.  Thank you!